# Root user in Elasticsearch 2.4.0 in Docker container

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, upgrade, elastic-stack

I am running ELK stack with Docker for log management with current configuration of ES 1.7, Logstash 1.5.4 and Kibana 4.1.4. Now I am trying to upgrade Elasticsearch to 2.4.0, found at https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/tar/elasticsearch/2.4.0/elasticsearch-2.4.0.tar.gz by using `tar.gz` file with Docker. As ES 2.X does not allow running it as root user, I have used

```
-Des.insecure.allow.root=true
```

option while running the elasticsearch service, yet my container doesn't start. The logs don't mention any problem.

```
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
100 874 100 874 0 0 874k 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 853k
//opt//log-management//elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch: line 134: hostname: command not found

Scheduler@0.0.0 start /opt/log-management/Scheduler
node scheduler-app.js

ESExportWrapper@0.0.0 start /opt/log-management/ESExportWrapper
node app.js
Jobs are registered
[2016-09-28 09:04:24,646][INFO ][bootstrap ] max_open_files [1048576]
[2016-09-28 09:04:24,686][WARN ][bootstrap ] running as ROOT user. this is a bad idea!
Native thread-sleep not available.
This will result in much slower performance, but it will still work.
You should re-install spawn-sync or upgrade to the lastest version of node if possible.
Check /opt/log-management/ESExportWrapper/node_modules/sync-request/node_modules/spawn-sync/error.log for more details
[2016-09-28 09:04:24,874][INFO ][node ] [Kismet Deadly] version[2.4.0], pid[1], build[ce9f0c7/2016-08-29T09:14:17Z]
[2016-09-28 09:04:24,874][INFO ][node ] [Kismet Deadly] initializing ...
Wed, 28 Sep 2016 09:04:24 GMT express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement at lib/express/index.js:60:5
Wed, 28 Sep 2016 09:04:24 GMT connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm module instead at node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:56:20
Wed, 28 Sep 2016 09:04:24 GMT connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read at node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:86:15
[2016-09-28 09:04:25,399][INFO ][plugins ] [Kismet Deadly] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-09-28 09:04:25,423][INFO ][env ] [Kismet Deadly] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/data (/dev/mapper/platform-data)]], net usable_space [1tb], net total_space [1tb], spins? [possibly], types [xfs]
[2016-09-28 09:04:25,423][INFO ][env ] [Kismet Deadly] heap size [7.8gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-09-28 09:04:25,455][WARN ][threadpool ] [Kismet Deadly] requested thread pool size [60] for [index] is too large; setting to maximum [24] instead
[2016-09-28 09:04:27,575][INFO ][node ] [Kismet Deadly] initialized
[2016-09-28 09:04:27,575][INFO ][node ] [Kismet Deadly] starting ...
[2016-09-28 09:04:27,695][INFO ][transport ] [Kismet Deadly] publish_address {10.240.118.68:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-09-28 09:04:27,700][INFO ][discovery ] [Kismet Deadly] ccs-elasticsearch/q2Sv4FUFROGIdIWJrNENVA
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: As `//opt//log-management//elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch: line 134: hostname: command not found`  was an error and docker image does not have `hostname` utility, I tried using `uname -n`command to get `HOSTNAME` in ES. Now it does not throw hostname error, but problem remains same. It does not start.
Is it correct alternative to use?

One more doubt, when I am using ES 1.7, which is up and running currently, `hostname` utility is not in there as well but it runs without any problem. Very confused.
Logs after using `uname -n` :

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1083  100  1083    0     0  1093k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1057k

> ESExportWrapper@0.0.0 start /opt/log-management/ESExportWrapper
> node app.js


> Scheduler@0.0.0 start /opt/log-management/Scheduler
> node scheduler-app.js

Jobs are registered
[2016-09-30 10:10:37,785][INFO ][bootstrap                ] max_open_files [1048576]
[2016-09-30 10:10:37,822][WARN ][bootstrap                ] running as ROOT user. this is a bad idea!
Native thread-sleep not available.
This will result in much slower performance, but it will still work.
You should re-install spawn-sync or upgrade to the lastest version of node if possible.
Check /opt/log-management/ESExportWrapper/node_modules/sync-request/node_modules/spawn-sync/error.log for more details
[2016-09-30 10:10:37,993][INFO ][node                     ] [Helleyes] version[2.4.0], pid[1], build[ce9f0c7/2016-08-29T09:14:17Z]
[2016-09-30 10:10:37,993][INFO ][node                     ] [Helleyes] initializing ...
Fri, 30 Sep 2016 10:10:38 GMT express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement at lib/express/index.js:60:5
Fri, 30 Sep 2016 10:10:38 GMT connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm module instead at node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:56:20
Fri, 30 Sep 2016 10:10:38 GMT connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read at node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:86:15
[2016-09-30 10:10:38,435][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Helleyes] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-09-30 10:10:38,455][INFO ][env                      ] [Helleyes] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/data (/dev/mapper/platform-data)]], net usable_space [1tb], net total_space [1tb], spins? [possibly], types [xfs]
[2016-09-30 10:10:38,456][INFO ][env                      ] [Helleyes] heap size [7.8gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-09-30 10:10:38,483][WARN ][threadpool               ] [Helleyes] requested thread pool size [60] for [index] is too large; setting to maximum [24] instead
[2016-09-30 10:10:40,151][INFO ][node                     ] [Helleyes] initialized
[2016-09-30 10:10:40,152][INFO ][node                     ] [Helleyes] starting ...
[2016-09-30 10:10:40,278][INFO ][transport                ] [Helleyes] publish_address {10.240.118.68:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-09-30 10:10:40,283][INFO ][discovery                ] [Helleyes] ccs-elasticsearch/wvVGkhxnTqaa_wS5GGjZBQ
[2016-09-30 10:10:40,360][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Helleyes] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x329b2977, /172.17.0.15:53388 => /10.240.118.69:9300]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:179)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-09-30 10:10:40,360][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Helleyes] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xdf31e5e6, /172.17.0.15:46846 => /10.240.118.70:9300]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:179)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-09-30 10:10:41,798][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Helleyes] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xcff0b2b6, /172.17.0.15:46958 => /10.240.118.70:9300]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:179)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-09-30 10:10:41,800][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Helleyes] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xb47caaf6, /172.17.0.15:53501 => /10.240.118.69:9300]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:179)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-09-30 10:10:43,302][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Helleyes] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x6247aa3f, /172.17.0.15:47057 => /10.240.118.70:9300]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:179)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-09-30 10:10:43,303][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Helleyes] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x1d266aa0, /172.17.0.15:53598 => /10.240.118.69:9300]], closing connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:179)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
```

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    [2016-09-30 10:10:44,807][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Helleyes] new_master {Helleyes}{wvVGkhxnTqaa_wS5GGjZBQ}{10.240.118.68}{10.240.118.68:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
    [2016-09-30 10:10:44,852][INFO ][http                     ] [Helleyes] publish_address {10.240.118.68:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
    [2016-09-30 10:10:44,852][INFO ][node                     ] [Helleyes] started
    [2016-09-30 10:10:44,984][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Helleyes] recovered [32] indices into cluster_state

Error after failed deployment

```
failed: [10.240.118.68] (item={u'url': u'http://10.240.118.68:9200'}) => {"content": "", "failed": true, "item": {"url": "http://10.240.118.68:9200"}, "msg": "Status code was not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "http://10.240.118.68:9200"}
```

EDIT 2: Even with `hostname`utility installed and working fine, containers don't start. Logs are same as EDIT 1.

EDIT 3: Container does start but is not reachable at address `http://nodeip:9200`. Out of 3 nodes, only 1 has 2.4 other 2 still has 1.7 and 2.4 is not the part of cluster. Inside container running 2.4, curl to `localhost:9200` gives running elasticsearch result, but unreachable from outside.

EDIT 4: I tried running basic installation of ES 2.4 on cluster, where in same set up ES 1.7 is working fine. I have run ES migration plugin to check if cluster is okay to run ES 2.4 and it gave me green. Basic installation details follow

Dockerfile

```
#Pulling SLES12 thin base image
FROM private-registry-1

#Author
MAINTAINER XYZ

# Pre-requisite - Adding repositories
RUN zypper ar private-registry-2

RUN zypper --no-gpg-checks -n refresh

#Install required packages and dependencies
RUN zypper -n in  net-tools-1.60-764.185 wget-1.14-7.1 python-2.7.9-14.1 python-base-2.7.9-14.1 tar-1.27.1-7.1 

#Downloading elasticsearch executable
ENV ES_VERSION=2.4.0
ENV ES_DIR="//opt//log-management//elasticsearch"
ENV ES_CONFIG_PATH="${ES_DIR}//config"
ENV ES_REST_PORT=9200
ENV ES_INTERNAL_COM_PORT=9300

WORKDIR /opt/log-management
RUN wget private-registry-3/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/${ES_VERSION}.tar/elasticsearch-${ES_VERSION}.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
RUN tar -xzvf ${ES_DIR}-${ES_VERSION}.tar.gz \
&& rm ${ES_DIR}-${ES_VERSION}.tar.gz \
&& mv ${ES_DIR}-${ES_VERSION} ${ES_DIR} 

#Exposing elasticsearch server container port to the HOST
EXPOSE ${ES_REST_PORT} ${ES_INTERNAL_COM_PORT}

#Removing binary files which are not needed
RUN zypper -n rm wget

# Removing zypper repos
RUN zypper rr caspiancs_common

#Running elasticsearch executable
WORKDIR ${ES_DIR}
ENTRYPOINT ${ES_DIR}/bin/elasticsearch -Des.insecure.allow.root=true
```

Build with

```
docker build -t es-test .
```

1) When Run with `docker run -d --name elasticsearch --net=host -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 es-test` as told in one of the comments and do `curl localhost:9200` inside the container or node which is running the container, I get correct response. I still can't reach to other nodes of cluster on 9200 port.

2) When Run with `docker run -d --name elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 es-test`and do `curl localhost:9200` inside the container, it works fine, but not at the node giving me error

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I still can't reach to other nodes of cluster on 9200 port.

EDIT 5: Using [this answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39883357/4519018), I got all three out of three containers running ES 2.4. But ES is unable to form a cluster with all these three containers. Network configuration is as follows 
`network.host : 0.0.0.0`, `http.port: 9200`,

```
#configure elasticsearch.yml for clustering
echo 'discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [ELASTICSEARCH_IPS] ' >> ${ES_CONFIG_PATH}/elasticsearch.yml
```

Logs got with `docker logs elasticsearch` are following:

```
[2016-10-06 12:31:28,887][WARN ][bootstrap                ] running as ROOT user. this is a bad idea!
[2016-10-06 12:31:29,080][INFO ][node                     ] [Screech] version[2.4.0], pid[1], build[ce9f0c7/2016-08-29T09:14:17Z]
[2016-10-06 12:31:29,081][INFO ][node                     ] [Screech] initializing ...
[2016-10-06 12:31:29,652][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Screech] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-10-06 12:31:29,684][INFO ][env                      ] [Screech] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [8.7gb], net total_space [9.7gb], spins? [unknown], types [rootfs]
[2016-10-06 12:31:29,684][INFO ][env                      ] [Screech] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-10-06 12:31:29,720][WARN ][threadpool               ] [Screech] requested thread pool size [60] for [index] is too large; setting to maximum [5] instead
[2016-10-06 12:31:31,387][INFO ][node                     ] [Screech] initialized
[2016-10-06 12:31:31,387][INFO ][node                     ] [Screech] starting ...
[2016-10-06 12:31:31,456][INFO ][transport                ] [Screech] publish_address {172.17.0.16:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2016-10-06 12:31:31,465][INFO ][discovery                ] [Screech] ccs-elasticsearch/YeO41MBIR3uqzZzISwalmw
[2016-10-06 12:31:34,500][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [Screech] failed to connect to master [{Bobster}{Gh-6yBggRIypr7OuW1tXhA}{172.17.0.15}{172.17.0.15:9300}], retrying...
ConnectTransportException[[Bobster][172.17.0.15:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: ConnectException[Connection refused: /172.17.0.15:9300];
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:1002)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:937)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:911)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.joinElectedMaster(ZenDiscovery.java:444)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:396)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$4400(ZenDiscovery.java:96)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$JoinThreadControl$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:1296)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /172.17.0.15:9300
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
```

Whenever I mention IP address of host running that container as `network.host`, I end up in old situation i.e. only one container running with ES 2.4, other two running 1.7.

Just saw that docker proxy is listening at 9300 or "I think" it is listening.

```
elasticsearch-server/src/main/docker # netstat -nlp | grep 9300
tcp        0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      6656/docker-proxy
```

Any leads on this?

Comment: Add the commands you use to create your container, Dockerfile, docker-compose. Also include `docker info` and `docker info`. There are too many variables otherwise.

Comment: You say that the log doesn't mention any problem, yet you have that : ```//opt//log-management//elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch: line 134: hostname: command not found
```

Comment: @michael_bitard Yes, sorry. I completely forgot that. I did not find anything on that error.

Comment: @Alkaline Containers are created and deployed using Ansible.

Comment: @michael_bitard As hostname command is not there in Docker image, I have tried using "uname -n | cut -d. -f1". Now there is no such error but still it fails.

Comment: try using the official docker containers `docker run elasticsearch`, if that runs the problem is with your Dockerfile, if not the problem is with your docker setup.

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile? How do you start elasticsearch? Did you publish/expose any ports?

Comment: @Hevlastka I am starting elasticsearch using Ansible. Container start but port 9200 on localhost is not reachable. I am exposing them in Dckerfile itself. Port 9200 and 9300.

Comment: Can you map the ports when you start the container using the `-p` flag and see what happens? 
Neither `EXPOSE` nor `--expose` depend on the host in any way; these rules don't make ports accessible from the host by default. Given the limitation of the `EXPOSE` instruction, as a Dockerfile author you should often include an `EXPOSE` rule only as a hint to which ports will provide services. It is up to the operator of the container to specify further networking rules.

Try mapping your ports while executing `docker run`, for example `-p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300`.

Comment: Try running docker image as container with flag `--net=host` to set the network stack same as host and check if 9200 is reachable from localhost.

Comment: are you running multiple es containers on different docker machine ? Also what does ELASTICSEARCH_IPS resolve to CONTAINER_PRIVATE_IP or CONTAINER_HOST_ADDRESS?

Comment: I am running 3 ES containers on 3 different node, which might be having other containers than ES. ELASTICSEARCH_IPS is an array of IPs which as IPs of all nodes running containers, with each host having  CONTAINER_HOST_ADDRESS.

Comment: Issue further given at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915050/elasticsearch-2-4-nodes-does-not-form-cluster-with-connecttransportexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to form cluster with following settings

`network.publish_host=CONTAINER_HOST_ADDRESS` i.e. address of node where the container is running.
`network.bind_host=0.0.0.0`
`transport.publish_port=9300`
`transport.publish_host=CONTAINER_HOST_ADDRESS`

`tranport.publish_port` is important when your are running ES behind proxy/ load balancer such nginx or haproxy.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html) for elasticsearch 2.x by default the network.host binds to `localhost`

You would need to explicitly set the `network.host:0.0.0.0` as specified in this [answer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html) :

Example:

```
ENTRYPOINT ${ES_DIR}/bin/elasticsearch -Des.insecure.allow.root=true -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Why 0.0.0.0? Why not CONTAINER_PRIVATE_IP or CONTAINER_HOST_ADDRESS?

Comment: You could use the CONTAINER_PRIVATE_IP or just  'network.host=_non_loopback_' but that would mean you cannot use loopback within container . 0.0.0.0 is more in line with what elasticsearch 1.7 .

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping your ports when you start the container using the -p flag.

Neither `EXPOSE` nor `--expose` depend on the host in any way; these rules don't make ports accessible from the host by default. Given the limitation of the `EXPOSE` instruction, as a `Dockerfile` author you should often include an `EXPOSE` rule only as a hint to which ports will provide services. It is up to the operator of the container to specify further networking rules.

Try mapping your ports while executing `docker run`, for example `docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 <image>:<tag>`